How can I get my Case statement to paste my formula in each cell
Disclaimer: I'm not very skilled with VBA yet and I know there's optimization to be done. I've been using this project as my learning tool
I have written a formula to calculate the rate based on specific criteria. Until now, I have simply used my code to write the formula in E3 then autofill it all the way to the bottom. I now have a need to make the formula dynamic based on another cell value. I have all that written up for a single cell, but I'm having trouble finishing it up.
At present, the code below is assessing the flag column as expected, but my formula is only being pasted into E3. The way I have it written is expected to do so, but I'm just not sure how to get it to copy into each row of column E, assessing the relative cell value of column M (ex: E3 based on value of M3, E4 based on value of M4, etc). I've tried replacing the line:
Range("E3").Select

with
Range("E3:E" & lr).Select

but that didn't work either. I've toyed with the idea of using a loop, but to my knowledge, these must have a defined range (please correct me if I'm wrong). My row ranges will always be changing from project to project and I don't have the skill as of yet to workaround that.
I've looked up other posts similar to mine, but I lack the experience to adjust them meaningfully to suit my uses.
Please let me know if I can clarify my request at all.
Here is what I have so far:
Sub TestZipExclLogic()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lr As Long

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In Range("M3:M" & lr)
Select Case rng.Value
    Case "True"
        Range("E3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R4C13:R13C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'GA Rates'!R4C12:R13C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:" & _
            "R75C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(" & _
            "RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC15<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15=""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R4C" & _
            "13:R8C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'PM Rates'!R4C12:R8C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14=""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PM Rates'!R2C1:R" & _
            "72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PM Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(A" & _
            "ND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15<>""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PM Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,1,1)," & _
            "IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope"",RC2=""Flat Rate Padded Envelope"")),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Small Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,4,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Flat Rate Box"",RC2" & _
            "=""Medium Flat Rate Box"",RC2=""Medium Flat Rate Boxes"")),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,5,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Large Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,6,1),IF(RC[-3]=""Oversized Package"",INDEX(GA_Comm!R2C2:R76C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC2,GA_Comm!R2C1:R76C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,GA_Comm!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Pac" & _
            "kage"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC14="""",RC15=""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15=""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),M" & _
            "ATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,1,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""" & _
            "Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15<>""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)))))))))))))))))))))))" & _
            ""
    Case "False"
        Range("E3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R4C13:R13C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'GA_Comm'!R4C12:R13C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:" & _
            "R75C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(" & _
            "RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC15<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15=""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R4C" & _
            "13:R8C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'PM_Comm'!R4C12:R8C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14=""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R" & _
            "72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(A" & _
            "ND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15<>""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,1,1)," & _
            "IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope"",RC2=""Flat Rate Padded Envelope"")),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Small Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,4,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Flat Rate Box"",RC2" & _
            "=""Medium Flat Rate Box"",RC2=""Medium Flat Rate Boxes"")),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,5,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Large Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,6,1),IF(RC[-3]=""Oversized Package"",INDEX(GA_Comm!R2C2:R76C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC2,GA_Comm!R2C1:R76C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,GA_Comm!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Pac" & _
            "kage"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC14="""",RC15=""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15=""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),M" & _
            "ATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,1,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""" & _
            "Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15<>""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)))))))))))))))))))))))" & _
            ""
End Select
Next rng

End Sub


rng.EntireRow.Columns("E").FormulaR1C1 = ...  Note there's rarely any need to select a range before working with it - that's an artifact of the way the macro recorder works.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

It certainly speeds up your code if you don't select them.

The formula you're inserting is nuts. You have 21 levels of IF nesting. RC[-3]="Oversized Package" looks wrong. There's no way that formula doesn't contain errors.

Not using a loop is the easiest fix
Sub TestZipExclLogic()
    Dim rng As Range, formulaRng As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 13).Resize(lr - 1, 1)
        Set formulaRng = rng.Offset(1, -8).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="True"
        formulaRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R4C13:R13C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'GA Rates'!R4C12:R13C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:" & _
                    "R75C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(" & _
                    "RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC15<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15=""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R4C" & _
                    "13:R8C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'PM Rates'!R4C12:R8C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14=""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PM Rates'!R2C1:R" & _
                    "72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PM Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(A" & _
                    "ND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15<>""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PM Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,1,1)," & _
                    "IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope"",RC2=""Flat Rate Padded Envelope"")),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Small Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,4,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Flat Rate Box"",RC2" & _
                    "=""Medium Flat Rate Box"",RC2=""Medium Flat Rate Boxes"")),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,5,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Large Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,6,1),IF(RC[-3]=""Oversized Package"",INDEX(GA_Comm!R2C2:R76C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC2,GA_Comm!R2C1:R76C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,GA_Comm!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Pac" & _
                    "kage"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC14="""",RC15=""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15=""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),M" & _
                    "ATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,1,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""" & _
                    "Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15<>""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)))))))))))))))))))))))" & _
                    ""
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="False"
        formulaRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R4C13:R13C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'GA_Comm'!R4C12:R13C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:" & _
                    "R75C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(" & _
                    "RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC15<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15=""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R4C" & _
                    "13:R8C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'PM_Comm'!R4C12:R8C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14=""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R" & _
                    "72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(A" & _
                    "ND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15<>""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,1,1)," & _
                    "IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope"",RC2=""Flat Rate Padded Envelope"")),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Small Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,4,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Flat Rate Box"",RC2" & _
                    "=""Medium Flat Rate Box"",RC2=""Medium Flat Rate Boxes"")),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,5,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Large Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,6,1),IF(RC[-3]=""Oversized Package"",INDEX(GA_Comm!R2C2:R76C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC2,GA_Comm!R2C1:R76C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,GA_Comm!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Pac" & _
                    "kage"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC14="""",RC15=""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15=""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),M" & _
                    "ATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,1,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""" & _
                    "Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15<>""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)))))))))))))))))))))))" & _
                    ""
        rng.AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub


Use rng.Offset(, -8) is the easy fix.  True and False are Boolean values and should not be enclosed in quotes.
Sub TestZipExclLogic()
    Const ColumnOffset As Long = -8
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
    For Each rng In Range("M3:M" & lr)
        Select Case rng.Value
            Case True
                rng.Offset(, ColumnOffset).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R4C13:R13C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'GA Rates'!R4C12:R13C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:" & _
                    "R75C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(" & _
                    "RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC15<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA Rates'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'GA Rates'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15=""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R4C" & _
                    "13:R8C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'PM Rates'!R4C12:R8C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14=""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PM Rates'!R2C1:R" & _
                    "72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PM Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(A" & _
                    "ND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15<>""""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PM Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,1,1)," & _
                    "IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope"",RC2=""Flat Rate Padded Envelope"")),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Small Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,4,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Flat Rate Box"",RC2" & _
                    "=""Medium Flat Rate Box"",RC2=""Medium Flat Rate Boxes"")),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,5,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Large Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM Rates'!R11C13:R17C13,6,1),IF(RC[-3]=""Oversized Package"",INDEX(GA_Comm!R2C2:R76C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC2,GA_Comm!R2C1:R76C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,GA_Comm!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Pac" & _
                    "kage"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC14="""",RC15=""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15=""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),M" & _
                    "ATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,1,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R3C13:R5C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""" & _
                    "Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15<>""""),INDEX('Express Rates'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'Express Rates'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'Express Rates'!R1C2:R1C10,0)))))))))))))))))))))))"
            Case False
                rng.Offset(, ColumnOffset).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R4C13:R13C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'GA_Comm'!R4C12:R13C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14="""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:" & _
                    "R75C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(" & _
                    "RC1=""Ground Advantage"",RC15<>"""",RC2<>""Oversized Package""),INDEX('GA_Comm'!R2C2:R75C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'GA_Comm'!R2C1:R75C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'GA_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3<>""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15=""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R4C" & _
                    "13:R8C21,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC16,'PM_Comm'!R4C12:R8C12,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R3C13:R3C21,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14=""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R" & _
                    "72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15="""",'Test Sheet'!RC14<>""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(A" & _
                    "ND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package"",RC2=""Thick Envelope"",RC2=""Large Envelope or Flat""),RC3=""No Cubic Pricing"",RC15<>""""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PM_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PM_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,1,1)," & _
                    "IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope"",RC2=""Flat Rate Padded Envelope"")),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Small Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,4,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",OR(RC2=""Flat Rate Box"",RC2" & _
                    "=""Medium Flat Rate Box"",RC2=""Medium Flat Rate Boxes"")),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,5,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Priority"",RC2=""Large Flat Rate Box""),INDEX('PM_Comm'!R11C13:R17C13,6,1),IF(RC[-3]=""Oversized Package"",INDEX(GA_Comm!R2C2:R76C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC2,GA_Comm!R2C1:R76C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,GA_Comm!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Pac" & _
                    "kage"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC14="""",RC15=""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH(ROUNDUP('Test Sheet'!RC7,0),'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15=""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC14,'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),M" & _
                    "ATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,1,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Legal Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,2,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",RC2=""Padded Flat Rate Envelope""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R3C13:R5C13,3,1),IF(AND(RC1=""Express"",OR(RC2=""" & _
                    "Package"",RC2=""Large Package""),RC15<>""""),INDEX('PME_Comm'!R2C2:R72C10,MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC15,'PME_Comm'!R2C1:R72C1,0),MATCH('Test Sheet'!RC8,'PME_Comm'!R1C2:R1C10,0)))))))))))))))))))))))"
        End Select
    Next rng

End Sub

Watch: Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)

Change this part to use the loop variable, instead of hard-coded E3:
For Each rng In Range("M3:M" & lr)
Select Case rng.Value
    Case "True"
        Range("E" & cstr(rng.row)).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(AND(RC1=""Ground A
...

